# Please add more sites to on topic help page regarding electronics

Tags: feature-request, question-quality

Questions about help with hobbyist electronics are one of the bigger sources of off-topic questions on Hardware Recommendations.

Because of this I request that three sites are considered for addition to the [on topic help](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

- [Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/) - the site about designing electronics
- [Arduino](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/)
- [Raspberry Pi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All done - I added them into a new bullet point down the bottom, in the list of "where else your question might be on topic" sites.

Comment: I would remove the "hobbyist" in the help article since it unnecessarily narrows it down and misrepresents the EE stack which welcomes professionals as well obviously. The wquakifier in my question was maybe a bit unnecessary in my question. Sorry about that

Comment: Thanks, @JanDorniak - I'll amend it to "hobbyist, consumer, or professional". Feels like it lacks description if I just leave it unqualified.

Comment: remove consumer since they are usually repair questions which are OT on the EE Stack

Comment: @JanDorniak I'm tempted to leave it in for those questions that aren't. The link there goes to the EE on-topic page, though, not the front page, so anyone it does send that way should also get a chance to read for themselves what they can ask.

Comment: ok, leave it that way and if there are complaints from EE it can be changed then. And the OT questions which I saw and would redirect there are not repair questions anyway.

Comment: One more thing: there is no direct link to the on-topic help article in the sidebar when asking a question, only links to meta.

Comment: Aye. Not one I have the power to change, unfortunately - that needs a CM and 6-8 weeks.

Comment: I was just in the middle of writing that _"hardware recommendations"_ is a confusing name but that's probably a hopeless case too?

Comment: Fairly, yes. We looked long and hard at the name when the site first launched, but nobody came up with anything better that actually worked.

Comment: true that, it would be hard to come up with anything better. I'll try to think of this and speak up when I believe I have a better name. One which sticks with me for the moment is "Information Technology Hardware". Although it might be bad too. Also, did you know that utility meters also fit into our rules?